# Remove Category title XML

Tags: magento-enterprise

How to remove or hide category listing title using Custom Layout Update?

This is my code so for.

```
<reference name="product_list_toolbar" after="content">
  <action method="setData"><data>_current_grid_mode</data><mode>grid</mode></action>
</reference>

<reference name="product_list">
  <action method="setColumnCount"><count>5</count></action>
</reference>
```

[image]

Comment: on which  position header or list postion,, can u give screen short

Comment: in a grid view category list

Comment: give a screen short

Comment: check it. I need to remove the title Microsoft Office 365

Comment: are you want for a particular category?

Comment: yes. only for 1 particular category page

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 2):

Since it is not added individually by XML it cannot be removed via XML.  As mentioned in Amit Bera's answer you change catalog/product.view.phtml or duplicate it if you need both options (with and without title).

However the easiest solution would be to hide this via CSS.

For all categories you could use:

```
.category-title { display: none; }
```

You said it was for a specific category page so you can further target it by going to the page and viewing the page source.  Attached to the  tag you can see the category's class name.  In your example this class name is most likely 'category-microsoft-office-365'.  Assuming that is correct you can use this CSS:

```
.category-microsoft-office-365 .category-title { display: none; }
```

This will hide the category title for only that specific category.

Answer (score 0):

first of `all it cannot remove using layout because this content is not coming from layout object`...It is coming from category 
object

```
if  you need this remove then got catalog/category/view.phtml...

 put some logic to hidden this.
```

Just commit  below code which
is show title

```
<div class="page-title category-title">
    <?php if($this->IsRssCatalogEnable() && $this->IsTopCategory()): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getRssLink() ?>" class="link-rss"><?php echo $this->__('Subscribe to RSS Feed') ?></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <h1><?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_category->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
</div>
```

**Or if you want for for a category then you can do
this   using below step:**

1)`create replicate of  view.phtml   as name customview.phtml and in customview.phtml commit title code`.

2)`add below on which set customview.phtml as it template`

here 49 particular cat id

```
<CATEGORY_49>
    <reference name="category.products" >
         <action method="setTemplate"><templatecatalog/category/customview.phtml</template></action>
 </CATEGORY_49>
```